# Display DIV-sub-1 when DIV-1 is clicked using a counter

Tags: jquery, counter

I am generating unique divs with PHP. Following is a sample of my HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="team-member-1"><img src="/theimage1.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="team-member-bio-1"><p>The team member's biography.</p></div>

  <div id="team-member-2"><img src="/theimage2.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="team-member-bio-2"><p>The team member's biography.</p></div>

  <div id="team-member-3"><img src="/theimage3.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="team-member-bio-3"><p>The team member's biography.</p></div>
</div>
```

The numbers at the end of each div id are what is being generated by the PHP counter. What I'd like to do with jQuery is show "team-member-bio-1" when the div "team-member-1" is clicked, show "team-member-bio-2" when the div "team-member-2" is clicked, etc. I know I could do this with a bunch of if else statements but I know that's not the most efficient way; I have around 36 team members on the page. I was thinking I could use a counter and add the number generated by the jQuery counter to the first part of each div name. Being fairly new to jQuery I'm a bit unsure of the best way to format everything to make it work.

Please let me know if you need me to provide any other information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to work with your existing code, you can use a generic selector and parse out the ID.

```
$('div[id^=team-member-]').click(function(){
    thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    bioId = thisId.substring(thisId.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
    var bioElement = $('#team-member-bio-'+bioId); // your bio div
});
```

See this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVYr9/).

The proper way to do this however would be to use a data attribute such as `data-bioid="1"` and, you should have a common class for jQuery to bind a click() even to such as `class="team-member"`, like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="team-member-1" class="team-member" data-bioid="1"><img src="/theimage1.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="team-member-bio-1"><p>The team member's biography.</p></div>
</div>
```

You can then look for a click on any of these classes and do something with the member bio:

```
$('.team_member').click(function(){
    bioId = $(this).data('bioid');   // the value of data-bio attribute
    var bioElement = $('#team-member-bio-'+bioId); // your bio div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[id^=team-member-]').click(function()
{
  $(this).next().first().css('display','block'); 
});
```

Comment: I think you need next() twice , sense team-member-bio would be next()

Comment: This will also break if the bio ever happens to not be `next()`

Comment: @Kir you could put selector in next() , see my edit to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This gets the last part of a sting in javascript

```
  id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('-')+1)   

  //split also works here
  var num = id.split("-")
  var newID  = "team-member-" + ((num[2] *1) + 1)
```

so maybe add a class on each div you want to be clickable

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="team-member-1" class="clickable"><img src="/theimage1.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="team-member-bio-1"><p>The team member's biography.</p></div>


$(function(){
   $('.clickable').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var lastChar = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('-')+1)
     nextid = "team-member-" + ((lastchar * 1) + 1) 
    $('#' + nextid ).show();
 });
});
```

EDIT:
other answer inspired me to make another solution for you , this should work just as good with much less code

```
$('div[id^=team-member-]').click(function()
{
  $(this).next($('div[id^=team-member-]')).show() 
});
```

-here it does not matter if there is any bio div , multiple bio divs , or anything else inbetween

Comment: What about member 100? The better way to get the numeric ID would be `id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('-')+1)` to account for numbers greater than 10.

Comment: ahhhh - good point - I also put another solution in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use image tag as key to find current clicked div . use `has()` to select particular element which has image tag.

```
  $('div[id*="team-member-"]:has(img)').click(function(){
        $(this).next().show('slow');
  });​
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KXBxE/)